# In Groovy, how do I get the value in an element with a specific attribute in XML

Tags: xml, groovy

I have a groovy script that compares an XML response to a JDBC query. I am trying to account for a scenario where I need to validate a XML value based on a specific attribute in the element.

Here is an example of the XML:

```
               <FormInstance id="Impairment_0111235228_2_174_477">
              <FormName>NEW MEDICAL HISTORY NOTE</FormName>
              <ProviderFormNumber>174</ProviderFormNumber>
              <FormResponse id="Imapairment_477_6">
                 <QuestionNumber>477</QuestionNumber>
                 <QuestionText>ExamOne Rx</QuestionText>
                 <AnswerChoice>
                    <AnswerChoiceText>ExamOne Result</AnswerChoiceText>
                    <OLifEExtension VendorCode="08" ExtensionCode="ImpairmentAttributeType">LBL</OLifEExtension>
                    <OLifEExtension VendorCode="08" ExtensionCode="ImpairmentAttributeSeq">2</OLifEExtension>
                 </AnswerChoice>
                 <OLifEExtension VendorCode="08" ExtensionCode="ImpairmentSequence">1</OLifEExtension>
                 <OLifEExtension VendorCode="08" ExtensionCode="QuestionSequence">6</OLifEExtension>
              </FormResponse>
           </FormInstance>
```

As you can see, there are several elements with the name "OLifEExtension", but with unique ExtensionCode attributes. I need to be able to compare the value by attribute. For example, using the XML above, if the attribute ExtensionCode = QuestionSequence, I expect to see a value of 6.

I have tried the following in my script:

```
    obj.questionSequence = xml.FormResponse.OLifEExtension.{'@ExtensionCode' == 'QuestionSequence'}

    obj.questionSequence = xml.FormResponse.{it.name() == 'OLifEExtension' && it.@ExtensionCode == 'QuestionSequence'}

    obj.questionSequence = xml.FormResponse.OLifEExtension.{it.@ExtensionCode == 'QuestionSequence'}
```

The syntax on all 3 examples appear to be correct because I don't get any errors when I run the script, but when I output results, it is always empty.

I also tried:

```
obj.questionSequence = xml.FormResponse.OLifEExtension[1]
```

This works, but the problem here is that QuestionSequence may not always exist in the same spot. It could be position 0 or 2. So, I really need it to work off the attribute name.

Also, the base of the script that I am using is in the response to this question if that is needed by anyone.

[Compare JDBC Response to an XML Response where number of nodes vary and order could change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41726812/compare-jdbc-response-to-an-xml-response-where-number-of-nodes-vary-and-order-co)

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, right after I ask the question, I figure it out. If anyone has a cleaner way to do it, I would appreciate it, but this seems to do the trick.

```
obj.questionSequence = xml.FormResponse.OLifEExtension.find{it.@ExtensionCode == 'QuestionSequence'}
```