# Is it possible to automate comparisons between database results with groovy script?

Tags: sql, json, groovy, comparison

I am in the process of migrating an application which currently performs all of its SQL calls internally (as part of the code) to Restful services so that the SQL calls are handled externally. I am in need of a smart way to test that these changes have no effect on the actual data that is retrieved from the database.

I was thinking it might be possible to write some automation tests against the APIs and then use groovy script to compare the results of both.

Using Soap UI

1: old SQL call - returns XML
2: New Restful call -returns JSON 
3: Compare both results.

The issue I have is that a direct call returns XML whereas the new call returns JSON.

I just need to know if this is a waste of time or if this is worth pursuing?

The only other option I can think of currently is to manually run two tests on both versions at the same time and observe any differences if they occur.

Thanks for taking the time to read. 
If you need any more detail please let me know but tried to keep it brief!

Comment: See if this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41726812/compare-jdbc-response-to-an-xml-response-where-number-of-nodes-vary-and-order-co/41746806#41746806

Comment: This could be helpful too: [Dynamically compare Rest XML/JSON response and JDBC using groovy array in SoapUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35706976)

Comment: Thanks guys really useful stuff.