# SOAP UI: Comparing JSON Response Array with JDBC XMLresponse

Tags: json, jdbc, groovy, soapui

I have a REST service which will give a **JSON response array** as below and I want to compare the API response with the JDBC XML response to make sure the data is corrent in the API response

[{ "id": 1, "first_name": "George", "last_name": "Bluth", "avatar": "Test1" },
{ "id": 2, "first_name": "Janet", "last_name": "Weaver", "avatar": "Test2" },
{ "id": 3, "first_name": "Emma", "last_name": "Wong", "avatar": "Test3" }]

I have connected the respected data source in the same Test Step in SOAP UI. Here is my sample JDBC Response from the Data source in XML format

```
<Results>
    <ResultSet FetchSize="10">
        <Row rowNumber="1">
            <id>1</id>
            <first_name>George</first_name>
            <last_name>Bluth</last_name>
            <avatar>Test1</avatar>
        </Row>
        <Row rowNumber="2">
            <id>1</id>
            <first_name>Janet</first_name>
            <last_name>Weaver</last_name>
            <avatar>Test2</avatar>'
        </Row>
            .
            .
            .
</Results>
```

Can anyone tell me how to compare each objects in the array with the corresponding data source value.

I tried make a groovy script to parse the JSON response to a variable using JsonSlurper. However, i am getting error

**CODE:**

```
def responseContent = testRunner.testCase.testSteps["Neme fof the test step"].testRequest.response.contentAsString
def Response = new JsonSlurper().parseText(responseContent)
log.info Code
```

> **Error Message:** Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object The current character read is ''
>   with an int value of 65279 Unable to determine the current character,
>   it is not a string, number, array, or object line number 1 index
>   number 0

Comment: show the jdbc response as well.

Comment: By the way, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472381/dynamically-compare-rest-xml-json-response-and-jdbc-using-groovy-array-in-soapui/35706976#35706976 and make the required changes for your case.

Comment: Hello Rao, Thanks for your reply. I have updated query with the Sample XML from the JDBC Data Source. Please refer the same.