# Compare JDBC response with REST API response in SoapUI using groovy script

Tags: rest, groovy, soapui

I've been trying to make groovy script that parses jdbc and REST response, put the results in a model and then compare them. I am following this answer: [Dynamically compare Rest XML/JSON response and JDBC using groovy array in SoapUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472381/dynamically-compare-rest-xml-json-response-and-jdbc-using-groovy-array-in-soapui), but not with much success. My jdbc response is below:

```
<Results>
    <ResultSet fetchSize="128">
        <Row rowNumber="1">
            <ID>BCE448A4DFB94C6892D957DB8275D2AC</ID>
            <NAME>SevDealRecord</NAME>
            <AMOUNT/>
            <CREATIONDATE>2012-06-20 11:31:48.0</CREATIONDATE>
            <MODIFICATIONDATE>2012-06-20 15:20:02.0</MODIFICATIONDATE>
            <CURRENCY>EUR</CURRENCY>
            <REFERENCEDATE>2012-06-20 00:00:00.0</REFERENCEDATE>
            <STATUSCODE>DPE_2</STATUSCODE>
            <STATUSDESCRIPTION>2 - Preliminary evaluation in progress (Direct PE)</STATUSDESCRIPTION>
            <ASSIGNEDTOUSERIQID>E506565555A6486FBA8FCC431F4E979E</ASSIGNEDTOUSERIQID>
            <ASSIGNTOUSERDISPLAYNAME>NMISO</ASSIGNTOUSERDISPLAYNAME>
            <WORKFLOWID>140AE208F9334FB9946BFEAF5C89CE18</WORKFLOWID>
            <WORKFLOWNAME>1 - Direct Private Equity</WORKFLOWNAME>
        </Row>
        <Row rowNumber="2">
            <ID>D4DBB1B906A04DE49AB1FF3EE4653180</ID>
            <NAME>T28678</NAME>
            <AMOUNT/>
            <CREATIONDATE>2012-06-21 13:45:36.0</CREATIONDATE>
            <MODIFICATIONDATE>2012-06-21 13:46:03.0</MODIFICATIONDATE>
            <CURRENCY>EUR</CURRENCY>
            <REFERENCEDATE>2012-06-21 00:00:00.0</REFERENCEDATE>
            <STATUSCODE>DRAFT</STATUSCODE>
            <STATUSDESCRIPTION>Draft{F}Brouillon</STATUSDESCRIPTION>
            <ASSIGNEDTOUSERIQID>E506565555A6486FBA8FCC431F4E979E</ASSIGNEDTOUSERIQID>
            <ASSIGNTOUSERDISPLAYNAME>NMISO</ASSIGNTOUSERDISPLAYNAME>
            <WORKFLOWID/>
            <WORKFLOWNAME/>
        </Row>
```

And here is REST response:

```
[{
    "id": "12CF6F8DA3B148D98D63A428EC7F8D7B",
    "name": "アコム株式会社",
    "amount1": null,
    "creationDate": null,
    "modificationDate": "2019-01-14T16:28:21.027+00:00",
    "currency": "USD",
    "referenceDate": "2019-01-04T00:00:00+00:00",
    "status": {
        "code": "DRAFT",
        "description": "Draft"
    },
    "assignedToUser": {
        "id": "E506565555A6486FBA8FCC431F4E979E",
        "displayName": "NMISO"
    },
    "assignedToGroup": null,
    "workflow": null
}, {
    "id": "AA4F19E5C8B34222865EFED293D52146",
    "name": "Lürssen",
    "amount1": null,
    "creationDate": null,
    "modificationDate": "2019-01-14T16:28:20.963+00:00",
    "currency": "USD",
    "referenceDate": "2019-01-04T00:00:00+00:00",
    "status": {
        "code": "DRAFT",
        "description": "Draft"
    },
    "assignedToUser": {
        "id": "E506565555A6486FBA8FCC431F4E979E",
        "displayName": "NMISO"
    },
    "assignedToGroup": null,
    "workflow": null
},
```

What I tried:

```
@groovy.transform.Canonical
class Model {
    def id
    def name
    def amount1
    def creationDate
    def modificationDate
    def currency
    def referenceDate
    def statusCode
    def statusDescription
    def assignedToUserIqid
    def assignedToUserDisplayName
    def assignedToGroup
    def workflowId
    def workflowName

    // this will accept jdbc row
    def buildJdbcData(row) {
        row.with {
            id = ID
            name = NAME
            amount1 = AMOUNT
            creationDate = CREATIONDATE
            modificationDate = MODIFICATIONDATE
            currency = CURRENCY
            referenceDate = REFERENCEDATE
            statusCode = STATUSCODE
            statusDescription = STATUSDESCRIPTION
            assignedToUserDisplayName = ASSIGNTOUSERDISPLAYNAME
            assignedToGroup = ASSIGNTOUSERDISPLAYNAME
            workflowId = WORKFLOWID
            workflowName = WORKFLOWNAME
        }
    }

    def buildJsonData(slurp){
        id = slurp.id
        name = slurp.name
        amount1 = slurp.amount1
        creationDate = slurp.creationDate
        modificationDate = slurp.modificationDate
        currency = slurp.currency
        referenceDate = slurp.referenceDate
        statusCode = slurp.status.code
        statusDescription = slurp.status.description
        assignedToUserIqid = slurp.assignedToUser.id
        assignedToUserDisplayName = slurp.assignedToUser.displayName
        assignedToGroup = slurp.assignedToGroup
        workflowId = slurp.workflow
    }
}

def jdbcResponse = context.expand('${JDBC_DealList#ResponseAsXml}')
def results = new XmlSlurper().parseText(jdbcResponse)

def jdbcDataObjects = []
results.ResultSet.Row.each { row ->
    jdbcDataObjects.add(new Model().buildJdbcData(row)) //Objects not added properly to the model
}
log.info jdbcDataObjects

def jsonResponse = testRunner.testCase.testSteps["Deals"].testRequest.response.contentAsString
def jsonObjects = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonResponse)
log.info jsonObjects



def jsonDataObjects = [] jsonDataObjects.add(new Model().buildJsonData(jsonObjects))
```

Now, the `log.info jdbcDataObjects` is giving me the WORKFLOWNAME elements from jdbc response. And `log.info jsonObjects` is giving me the whole JSON model, and I am not sure how to add all the elements to the above defined Model? Some help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please follow entire script in the referring thread (of the question) which solves the issue.

Comment: @Rao, I did, and the result that I am getting is the array of last element from JDBC/REST responses in the jdbcDataObjects/jsonDataObjects, like list with workflowName/workflow. Is there a way to store all the elements in the list and compare them?

Comment: Sorry, but you did not seem to have complete script which you referred, assertion part is missing above.

Answer (score -1):

In previous project ,we did this but for Soap not REST.but I believe,  you can follow same approach. 
1.we put query in Execel -ESMQuery1
2.Execel had 2 columns. First node to compare,second DB value to compare.
Eg- //soap/xmlnode1     ESMQuery1(UserName)
Here UserName is column name.
3.You simply need to create loop for all nodes mentioned and resolve ESMQuery(UserName).

Instead of xmlpath you can use Json path.

Thanks.